# Eclipse/Java/Android - View a Bitmap with Debugger

Tags: java, android, eclipse

While working with the debugger, is it possible to look to a bitmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can. just write bitmap bytes on your local hard drive at runtime and you can preview it.